# Linebreak does not work in section headings modified with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking

I have a problem with long sub/section headings: `\\` is not wirking.

As I'm new to Latex, I adopted this beautiful template http://www.fluortools.com/misc/LaTeXtemplate and modified it for my needs.

However, right now, I am stuck with linebreaks in sub/section headings.

Here's a  MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[scaled]{berasans}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono} 
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,includehead,headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations,decorations.pathmorphing,arrows,matrix,positioning,patterns}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\selectcolormodel{cmyk}
 \newcommand\boxedSection[3]{{%
%
     \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=#3,line width=1.0pt]
         \node[anchor=east,rectangle,draw] at (0,0) (counter) {\textbf{#2}};
             \draw (counter.south west)  ++(.0pt,.5pt)-- ++($(\linewidth,0) - (2.5pt,0)$);
\node [right of=counter,anchor=west]{#1};
     \end{tikzpicture}
 }}
 \newcommand\boxedSectionB[3]{{%
%
     \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=#3,line width=1pt]
         \node[anchor=east,rectangle,draw,fill=black] at (0,0) (counter) {\color{white}\textbf{#2}};
             \draw (counter.south west) ++(.0pt,.5pt)-- ++($(\linewidth,0) - (2.5pt,0)$);
\node [right of=counter,anchor=west]{#1};
     \end{tikzpicture}
 }}
\newcommand\boxedsection[1]{\boxedSectionB{#1}{\thesection}{2mm}}
\newcommand\boxedsubsection[1]{\boxedSection{#1}{\thesubsection}{1.7mm}}
\newcommand\boxedsubsubsection[1]{\boxedSection{#1}{\thesubsubsection}{1.5mm}}
 \titleformat{\section}[hang]%
     {\usekomafont{section}}%
     {}%
     {.0em}%
     {\filright\boxedsection}%

 \titleformat{\subsection}[hang]%
     {\usekomafont{subsection}}%
     {}%
     {.0em}%
     {\filright\boxedsubsection}%

 \titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]%
     {\usekomafont{subsubsection}}%
     {}%
     {.0em}%
     {\filright\boxedsubsubsection}%

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{1.5cm}{-1cm}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{1.5cm}{-1cm}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{6pt}{6pt}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{}{0pt}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\subsection{This title is really really really long so I'd liked to have a \\line break but instead is just go on and on ...}

\end{document}
```

As soon as I remove the boxedSection part in titleformat, linebreak with `\\` works again, but of course the nice layout is removed as well.

Could somebody please modify the MWE so that linebreak works again, but the nice layout is kept.

Thanks a lot!!

Mischko

**EDIT**
So I found a solution which works well for my purpose.
As touhami suggests I added `text width=13cm` after `anchor=west` 
and removed the line in the boxedSection while leaving the boxedSectionB unchanged.
So the code looks like this:

```
     \newcommand\boxedSection[3]{{%
%
     \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=#3,line width=1.0pt]
         \node[anchor=east,rectangle,draw] at (0,0) (counter) {\textbf{#2}};   
\node [right of=counter,anchor=west,text width=13cm]{#1};
     \end{tikzpicture}
 }}
```

And the results looks like this:
[image]

Comment: you need to change `\node [right of=counter,anchor=west]{#1};` to `\node [right of=counter,anchor=west,text width=SOME LENGTH]{#1};`

Comment: Thanks! Linebreak works automatically and manually, if changed as you suggested. However, the layout is really mixed up. See Edit. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: I am not sure this is the best way, but you can try `anchor=south west` if it's too above try `anchor=south west,yshift=-SOME LENGTH,`

Comment: what about `yshift=-.5cm`

Comment: You are right the shift is good, but it still doesn't look really good, does it? I am not really satifsfied with the underlining.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand, I will see what I can do.

Comment: If I understand, may be you need to change `text width=13cm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Here is another suggestion without package `titlesec`. Now there are no rules below the headings.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{scrbook}[2015/10/03]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[scaled]{berasans}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono} 
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=3cm,top=2.5cm,includehead,headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsubsectionnumdepth}% subsubsection numbered

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  font=\normalsize,
  %indent=-1em
]{section,subsection,subsubsection}

\newcommand*\BoxedSectionNumber[2]{{%
  \setlength\fboxrule{1pt}%
  \setlength\fboxsep{#2}%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}{%
    \colorbox{darkgray}{\textcolor{white}{\csname the#1\endcsname}}%
  }{\fbox{\csname the#1\endcsname}}%
  \hspace*{2\fboxsep}%
}}

\renewcommand*\sectionformat{\BoxedSectionNumber{section}{2mm}}
\renewcommand*\subsectionformat{\BoxedSectionNumber{subsection}{1.7mm}}
\renewcommand*\subsubsectionformat{\BoxedSectionNumber{subsection}{1.5mm}}

\newsavebox\SectionNumberBox

\renewcommand*\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \sbox{\SectionNumberBox}{\hspace*{#2}#3}%
  \noindent\usebox\SectionNumberBox%
  \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-\wd\SectionNumberBox\relax}{#4}%
  \par\nobreak%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\begin{document}
\section{Section title}
\blindtext

\subsection{This title is really really really long so I'd liked
      to have a line break but instead is just go on and on ...}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Subsubsection title}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

If you uncomment `indent=-1em` you will get

[image]

---

**Original answer**

Note that the usage of package `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended. You will get warnings by KOMA-Script and `titlesec`.

Here is a suggestion without `titlesec` and `tikz` that needs at least KOMA-Script version 3.19a (current on CTAN).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{scrbook}[2015/10/03]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[scaled]{berasans}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono} 
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,includehead,headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsubsectionnumdepth}% subsubsection numbered

\RedeclareSectionCommands[font=\normalfont]{section,subsection,subsubsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=-1.5cm,
  afterskip=1cm,
  font=\normalfont
]{section,subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-12pt,
  afterskip=6pt,
  font=\normalfont
]{subsubsection}

\newcommand*\sectionnumberfboxsep{2mm}
\newcommand*\subsectionnumberfboxsep{1.7mm}
\newcommand*\subsubsectionnumberfboxsep{1.5mm}

\renewcommand*\sectionformat{{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{\sectionnumberfboxsep}%
  \setlength\fboxrule{1pt}%
  \colorbox{black}{\bfseries\textcolor{white}{\thesection}}%
}}
\renewcommand*\subsectionformat{{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{\subsectionnumberfboxsep}%
  \setlength\fboxrule{1pt}%
  \fbox{\bfseries\thesubsection}%
}}
\renewcommand*\subsubsectionformat{{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{\subsubsectionnumberfboxsep}%
  \setlength\fboxrule{1pt}%
  \fbox{\bfseries\thesubsubsection}%
}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}{%
    \leavevmode\rlap{\rule[\dimexpr-\sectionnumberfboxsep-1pt\relax]{\textwidth}{1pt}}%
    \parbox[b]{3em}{#3}\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-3em}{#4}\par\nobreak%
  }{%
  \ifstr{#1}{subsection}{%
    \leavevmode\rlap{\rule[\dimexpr-\subsectionnumberfboxsep-1pt\relax]{\textwidth}{1pt}}%
    \parbox[b]{4em}{#3}\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-4em}{#4}\par\nobreak%
  }{%
  \ifstr{#1}{subsubsection}{%
    \leavevmode\rlap{\rule[\dimexpr-\subsubsectionnumberfboxsep-1pt\relax]{\textwidth}{1pt}}%
    \parbox[b]{4.75em}{#3}\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.75em}{#4}\par\nobreak%
  }{%
    \@hangfrom{\hspace*{#2}#3}{#4}%
  }}}%
}
\makeatletter

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\begin{document}
\section{Section title}
\blindtext
\subsection{This title is really really really long so I'd liked to have a line break but instead is just go on and on ...}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Subsubsection title}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks esdd for your detailled answer. Yeah, i know, I always get these warnings, but as the result looks ok I just ignored it ;). But of course a solution without titlesec would be perfect. I am not really happy, how the multiline title looks like. I think the title should not be higher than the counter. Maybe it's possible to enlarge the counter in such a way? Or maybe you'll have a better solution in mind? Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you really want different sizes of the numbers depending on the length of the titles? Then you may get a subsection number that is bigger than the section number ... And if the numbers are larger they are also wider. So the space for the title is smaller and may be there is an additional line needed. If you can not shorten your titles to one line then it could be better to use an other layout. Additionally note that the line below the title separates the title from the regarding contents.

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right that enlarging the counter is not a good idea. I found a solution which works well for me (see Edit). However, I continued using tikz, since I am not able to make these changes in your suggested code. So I still get warnings. So if you have time, maybe you can change your version by removing the line and adjusting the height of the title? Thanks!

Comment: @Mischko See my updated answer.